# Obtaining the best quality from a resized image?

Tags: image, image-processing

I have a set of beautiful pictures of oil paintings. The image resolution is typically 3000 x 2000 and I need to reduce these to 800 x 533 for display in a computer screen slide show.  I've been doing an image resize with Irfan View, setting the horizontal dimension to 800 but I'm wondering if there might be a better technique  that makes the resized image look better.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You may want to read some of [these](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=image+resizing&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C3&as_sdtp=) papers and check if those authors have a code available. MATLAB uses bicubic interpolation for resizing, so you need something better than that. I don't know what IrfanView uses.

Comment: Definitely take a look at image retargeting.  The technique specifically focuses on ensuring that the entire scene is not compromised while resizing the image.  A good example is the Seam Carving approach - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qadw0BRKeMk.  BTW @ParagS.Chandakkar pointed to a Google Scholar webpage, and Seam Carving is the first paper that appears!  I wrote an implementation of Seam Carving in Java for a Coursera course I took on Algorithms.  Check it out! https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r08yayshqz528z6/AABjGjW0d4OkNLVgtvo4CDpya

Comment: Implementation of Seam Carving is available in the ImageMagick suite. See the discussion and the links [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=10314&p=32464)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The retargeting and Seam Carving look interesting but I don't have access to these and I need to resize 65 images right away. I found an article that recommended Photoshop to first do bicubic resampling for the down sample, and then do a pass of  their unsharp mask to sharpen the image. It looks very good, certainly better than IrfanView, even with the IrfanView sharpening pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an interpolation method often referred to as "sinc/lanczos" (sinc-filters are a family of filters, and Lanczos is the most common implementation), which is made to prevent precisely the blurring that can occur with bicubic and similar (monotonous) filters. It basically contains a sharpening mask in its definition, which enhances finer features. This method of resizing is available in ImageMagick (good free tool for batch-converstions), Gimp and PhotoShop, but I haven't been able to ascertain whether it is an option in Irfan View.

A very thorough introduction to Lanczos is given at Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_resampling

A more practical overview can be found in the (extremely extensive!) ImageMagick documentation: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/#lanczos

As with all sharpening algorithms, it can generate artifacts (e.g. "ringing"), so in my experience it works best on rather busy images (such as oil paintings).

Comment: Thanks. The take away for me is that downsampling absolutely blurs the image and some sharpening step is needed to recover the detail, whether it's Irfan View's "Sharpen," something in PhotoShop or ,what you're talking about.  PhotoShop's Smart Sharpen is working well for me now, (I switched from the Unsharp Mask) so for this project I'll stick with it.